# Aspx Calendar: SelectedDate in Page_Load and Btn_Click

Tags: asp.net, calendar

In Page_Load, I retrieved a Date datatype variable from a MySQL table and display it in the calendar as shown below.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

Dim startdate As Date = objDBPromotion.getStartDateByPromoID(id)
startdateCalendar.VisibleDate = startdate
startdateCalendar.SelectedDate = startdate
```

In Btn_Click, I want to be able to click on a different date in the calendar and a messagebox will print out the new date selected. This is what i did.

```
Protected Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click

Dim selecteddate = startdateCalendar.SelectedDate.ToString()
MsgBox(selecteddate)
```

However, the messagebox displays the value of variable 'startdate'. Or that the value of SelectedDate did not change. How do i go about doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating it manually like:

```
startdateCalendar.SelectedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(YourtextBox.Text, startdateCalendar.Format, null);
Dim selecteddate = startdateCalendar.SelectedDate.ToString()  
MsgBox(selecteddate)
```

I belive this will work..

Comment: I'm sorry. What am i supposed to replace parameters YourtextBox.Text and startdateCalendar.Format with?

Since the first parameter should be the date to be parsed. But the date i'm trying to parse is startdateCalendar.SelectedDate no?

Comment: I believe you have markup like this: `Code`<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="YourtextBox" /><asp:CalendarExtender ID="startdateCalendar" runat="server" TargetControlID="YourtextBox" Format="MMMM d, yyyy" /> <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSave" CausesValidation="false" onClick="btnSave_Click" /> `code`